# How to find out the real type of `duration_cast<microseconds>(steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count()`

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

How to find the real type of the expresstion below:
`std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();`

I find the answer is `long int` through `typeid().name()` .

As i browse the related source code, i find the type should be `_Rep`.

I wonder that how to know the exact return type trough reading the source code.

```
/// duration
template<typename _Rep, typename _Period>
struct duration
{
    typedef _Rep                        rep;
    typedef _Period                     period;
...
    // 20.11.5.2 observer
    constexpr rep
    count() const
    { return __r; }
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Look for a statement that looks something like [this](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/chrono#L1124):

```
typedef duration<long long,        micro> microseconds;
```

In this case, the first template parameter (`long long`) is bound to the type `_Rep` in the `duration` template.